# Determining Angle Measure in a Triangle with Given Side Lengths Equation

Tags: trigonometry

I have a triangle with side lengths $a, b,$ and $c$ units, if the equation between the sides is given by $a^2+b^2=c^2+\sqrt{3}ab$, how can i find the value of angle C.
i know that the answer must come out to be 30 degrees I'd be happy if someone explained how

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Please see [Law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a $\triangle\text{ABC}$, we know that (for **EVERY** triangle):

$$
\begin{cases}
\angle\alpha+\angle\beta+\angle\gamma=\pi\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\left|\text{A}\right|}{\displaystyle\sin\angle\alpha}=\frac{\displaystyle\left|\text{B}\right|}{\displaystyle\sin\angle\beta}=\frac{\displaystyle\left|\text{C}\right|}{\displaystyle\sin\angle\gamma}\\
\\
\left|\text{A}\right|^2=\left|\text{B}\right|^2+\left|\text{C}\right|^2-2\left|\text{B}\right|\left|\text{C}\right|\cos\angle\alpha\\
\\
\left|\text{B}\right|^2=\left|\text{A}\right|^2+\left|\text{C}\right|^2-2\left|\text{A}\right|\left|\text{C}\right|\cos\angle\beta\\
\\
\left|\text{C}\right|^2=\left|\text{A}\right|^2+\left|\text{B}\right|^2-2\left|\text{A}\right|\left|\text{B}\right|\cos\angle\gamma
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

So, when we know that:

$$\left|\text{A}\right|^2+\left|\text{B}\right|^2=\left|\text{C}\right|^2+\left|\text{A}\right|\left|\text{B}\right|\sqrt{3}\tag2$$

Using the fifth equation of $(1)$ we can see:

$$\left|\text{A}\right|^2+\left|\text{B}\right|^2=\left|\text{A}\right|^2+\left|\text{B}\right|^2-2\left|\text{A}\right|\left|\text{B}\right|\cos\angle\gamma+\left|\text{A}\right|\left|\text{B}\right|\sqrt{3}\tag3$$

Subtracting $\left|\text{A}\right|^2+\left|\text{B}\right|^2$, from both sides:

$$0=\left|\text{A}\right|\left|\text{B}\right|\sqrt{3}-2\left|\text{A}\right|\left|\text{B}\right|\cos\angle\gamma=\left|\text{A}\right|\left|\text{B}\right|\left(\sqrt{3}-2\cos\angle\gamma\right)\tag4$$

Now, we know that $\left|\text{A}\right|\left|\text{B}\right|$ can not be zero, so we need to have:

$$\sqrt{3}-2\cos\angle\gamma=0\space\Longrightarrow\space\angle\gamma=\arccos\left(\frac{\displaystyle\sqrt{3}}{\displaystyle2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{6}\space\text{rad}=30^\circ\tag5$$